# `SessionFactory` and `Session` objects can't work with "try-with-resource"?

Tags: java, hibernate

When using hibernate, I would like to see if `SessionFactory` and `Session` objects can work with "try-with-resource", so that I can't ignore invoking their `close()` methods:

```
try (SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()){

    session.beginTransaction();

    Customer customer = new Customer();
    customer.setFirstName("James");
    customer.setLastName("Bond");
    customer.setSsn(999998);
    customer.setAddressLine1("1111 S St");
    customer.setCity("London");
    customer.setState("LDN");
    customer.setCountry("UK");

    session.save(customer);

    session.getTransaction().commit();

    // session.close();                                                                                                                                                        
    // sessionFactory.close();                                         

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I get the errors however:

```
CustomerTest.java:12: error: incompatible types: try-with-resources not applicable to variable type
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
                       ^
    (SessionFactory cannot be converted to AutoCloseable)
CustomerTest.java:18: error: incompatible types: try-with-resources not applicable to variable type
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()){
                ^
    (Session cannot be converted to AutoCloseable)
2 errors
```

Does it mean that `SessionFactory` and `Session` objects can't work with "try-with-resource", because the two classes don't implement `AutoCloseable` interface?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does it mean that `SessionFactory` and `Session` objects can't work with
>   "try-with-resource", because the two classes don't implement
>   `AutoCloseable` interface?

Yes, that's exactly what it means.

If you take a look at newer versions of Hibernate, however, you'll find that both [`SessionFactory`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html) and [`Session`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html) do implement the `AutoCloseable` interface there.

I think the change was made in Hibernate 5, so upgrading your version of Hibernate could be a potential solution.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in hibernate version 5. If you can upgrade to version 5, please use this. Supported Jira ticket

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8898

For project which cannot upgrade, for that we can implement our own **CloseableSession** interface.

```
public class CloseableSession implements AutoCloseable {

    private final Session session;

    public CloseableSession(Session session) {
        this.session = session;
    }

    public Session getSession() {
        return session;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
try (CloseableSession session = new CloseableSession(
                sessionFactory.openSession())) {

}
```

Comment: what if a `transaction` has begun using the session? will that transaction get rollbacked? since the session object is within the paranthesis, we cannot close the transaction inside catch!

Comment: @Sanal S: Simply place your tx."commit()" and "tx. rollback()" inside of a nested try/catch block.